# Call a class function in one module from another

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem updating a textbox in my gui. The code looks like the following in principle:

```
    # The Static_textbox module
    # -------------------------

    class TP_textbox(tk.LabelFrame):


        def __init__(self, master = None,bg='#000000'):

            tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master,text = 'Information')

            self.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 1,rowspan = 1, 
                      padx = 15, pady = 15,sticky = tk.N+tk.W + tk.S+tk.E)

            self.create()


        def create(self):    
            self.v = tk.StringVar()
            self.v.set('Choose time interval and press the "Read data" button to load data')
            self.textbox = tk.Label(self, textvariable = self.v, 
                                    anchor=tk.W, justify=tk.LEFT, font=("Arial", 10, 'bold'))
            self.textbox.grid()        
            print 'not again!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!'


        def update_textbox(self,TEXT):

            self.v.set(TEXT)
            self.update_idletasks()         




    # Module calling Static_textbox
    # -----------------------------

    import Static_textbox

    def createPickel(my_dir = u'/test_data', 
                     start = ['2012','1','2','12','45'],
                     stop = ['2012','6','2','12','45'],
                     filterVal = "filtered",
                     myData = transpaper_DataHolder.DataHolder()):

        update_info = Static_textbox.TP_textbox()

        infoText = 'Locating data on server...'
        update_info.update_textbox(infoText)
```

I realize that the line "update_info = Static_textbox.TP_textbox()" executes the whole module including the create function and thus creates a new textbox on top the old. Obviously I want to call only the update function in the static_text module but how is this done? I'm new to this object oriented programming...sorry for stupid question.

EDIT:

After reading the answer and comments below I assume that the solution should be something like the following

Create the textbox object in the main module and send it to a "data holder" module:

```
# Main module

import Static_textbox
import transpaper_DataHolder

    def __init__(self, root):
    """ """
        self.Data = transpaper_DataHolder.DataHolder() #class that holds data
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        root.title(""" FerryBox Tools """)
        self._setupMainWindow()

    def _setupMainWindow(self):
        TextObj = Static_textbox.TP_textbox(root)
        self.Data.setTextObj(TextObj)
```

A data holder module from which you can call the "update_textbox" function in the textbox object:

```
# Data holder module

class DataHolder(object):

        def setTextObj(self,TextObj):
            self.TextObj = TextObj

        def getTextObj(self):
            return self.TextObj
```

The "update_textbox" will then be called from several different modules:

```
# Typical call from other modules       

import transpaper_DataHolder

def createPickel(my_dir = u'/test_data', 
         start = ['2012','1','2','12','45'],
         stop = ['2012','6','2','12','45'],
         filterVal = "filtered",
         myData = transpaper_DataHolder.DataHolder()):  

    Data = myData

    infoText = 'Locating data on server...'
    TextObj = Data.getTextObj()
    TextObj.update_textbox(infoText)
```

This does not work however..no errors but the textbox isn't updated. Any sugestions?

Comment: Don't take the TK library as an example of OOP. It really isn't.

Comment: a bit off-topic: somewhere in the docs iirc Guido van Rossum states that tkinter is still around because it was first there. PyQt might be the more valuable choice, if you plan to stick with GUI programming.

Comment: @benjamin Just googled PyQt and wish I new about this 3 months ago when I started this project..

Comment: @DanielRoseman Don't know what OOP means...do you have a solution to my question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I'm not sure what you mean about the OOP comment. While it's true that Tkinter widgets aren't 100% pure python objects, you can treat them as such. All of my Tkinter apps use OOP principles.

Comment: @user2613825: don't worry too much about what Guido says. I respect  him greatly, but it's just one opinion, and he probably never, ever writes GUIs. Tkinter is perfectly fine to learn on, and is quite good for most of what you'll ever need from a GUI toolkit. Tkinter is a very good, pragmatic choice for many, many problems.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot treat `update_textbook` as a static function since it's not declared as static (and its functionality implies that it receives an object).

In python the `self` parameter refers to the instance of the class. Therefor you can only use it in this case as follows:

```
# create a new text-book
textbook = Static_textbox.TP_textbox()

# update the textbook with some text
textbook.update_textbox("123")
```

Comment: This is what is done in the code I submitted above. However, I do not want to create a new text box. I want to call the update function "update_textbox" only, without creating a new text box..

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are saying. Is it impossible to change a tk.Label (whithin a tk.LabelFrame) created in one module, by calling it from another?

Comment: @user2613825: you can't update the label in the widget unless you first create the widget. You simply _must_ call TP_textbox() at least once, or there's nothing to update. When you do, save what it returns. From that point on, call the `update_textbox` method of the object that it returns. In other words, you call TP_textbox() exactly once to create the widget, then call `update_textbox()` as many times as you want.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thank you for explaining! I have updated the question above, trying to follow your suggestion, but I still haven't succeeded. Can you see what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to define some stuff as global perhaps?